# How to remove the php gettext extension

Tags: php, gettext

I would like to know if there is any way I can remove the gettext extension without re-compiling php?

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: Yes, a framework I'm using has it's own _() function, If I try to run my application without compiling php w/ gettext disabled it will tell me that the _() function is already defined.

Answer (score 2):

Only when the gettext was installed as a loadable PHP extension. Check your PHP configuration (php.ini) for `extension` lines. If you want users to be unable to use gettext you can use the PHP `disable_functions` configuration directive to disable the gettext functions, from the PHP manual:

> disable_functions string
>   This
>   directive allows you to disable
>   certain functions for security
>   reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited
>   list of function names.
>   disable_functions is not affected by
>   Safe Mode. This directive must be set
>   in php.ini For example, you cannot set
>   this in httpd.conf.

Comment: I have tried : disable_functions gettext
but its not doing anything

Comment: Try `disable_functions('_')` maybe

Comment: This, however does not work for me :-(

Comment: `disable_functions` doesn't make functions go away. It just makes them throw an error when called. You still get an error if you try to redefine a builtin function, even if it's disabled.